# Continuously erroring jobs in Sidekiq because of lack of database connections in pool

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, background-process, sidekiq

I am just really fundamentally misunderstanding something about the purpose of queuing jobs in a background processor. Why do jobs begin when there are no database connections left? Here is the error I continue to get:

```
could not obtain a database connection within 5 seconds (waited 5.397317172 seconds). The max pool size is currently 25; consider increasing it.
```

I don't know how I am supposed to tell a job to not execute until there is a database connection available. I have looked everywhere. I sort of thought that was the purpose of queuing a job... to wait until the basic resources necessary for execution were available.

My db connection pool was at the default 5. It's at 25 now, and this is on a utility instance with no web server running at all.

What can I do to ensure that my jobs don't just fail like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, sidekiq creates **25** Processors. So you have to set your AR connection pool size as **25**(*Always set the pool size setting to something close or equal to the number of Processors*).